# How to deploy AIR files to Samsung TV with SmartTV

Tags: deployment, adobe, air, samsung-smart-tv

We managed to get hold of a new Samsung TV that support AIR. I followed the few example files out there that show how to setup an AIR for TV file in Flashbuilder and my packaged export is an .airi file. So far so good.

The problem I'm having though is how to deploy this file to the TV. I tried copying it to a usb key but can't find a menu item to import it. Even when logged in with a developer account into smartTV.

Also tried to deploy via apache webserver as you do with html widgets, but no success.

Does anyone know how to deploy AIR files to a Samsung TV?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out that you have to do following steps in order to get your AIR app running:

- Create your AIR project with air version 2.6
- Compile and pack your AIR applications as an .airi file
- Unzip the .airi file
- Add a config.xml with your desired configuration to the unzipped folders
- Make sure the config.xml has these settings

  ```
  <flashplayer>y</flashplayer>
  <apptype>13</apptype>
  ```
- Zip up the files again and deploy via
  local server as documented in the
  Samsung documentation

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [Samsung TV hello world](http://www.greenhughes.com/content/quothello-worldquot-app-samsung-internettv) blog entry (I haven't tried it yet). The instructions are related to a standard web app, but it may also work with your AIR app.

In case this blog dissappears, the key Samsung document he references is [here](http://pages.samsung.com/appscheduler/guides/%5B2010%5DUser%20Application%20Guide%5BVer%202.00%5D.pdf).

You may also find the details you need on this [video](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/max-2010-envision/learn-about-the-samsung-sdk-to-distribute-your-air-apps-to-samsung-smart-tvs/).

Comment: Hi Haraldini - If you find an answer useful, you should upvote it so good answers come to the top.